# Updating mysql database through php with HTTP POST methods

Tags: php, mysql

It executes on application perfectly I double checked it. It sends all parameters properly and the problem is in php script it doesn't execute the query (update,delete) it execute the insert query properly. The php script works perfect with html form but I don't know where the problem is.

Here is my php script:

```
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "locator";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
    $uMail = $_POST['u_mail'];
    $uIMEI = $_POST['u_IMEI'];
    $uName = $_POST['u_name'];
    $uPass = $_POST['u_pass'];
    $tName = $_POST['t_names'];
    $tIMEI = $_POST['t_IMEIs'];
    $tDesc = $_POST['t_desc'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE user_master SET t_names='$tName',t_IMEIs='$tIMEI',t_desc= '$tDesc'      WHERE u_mail = '$uMail' AND u_IMEI = '$uIMEI'");
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: P.S. I believe your keyboard is missing some keys. So you might want to check that.

Comment: bt is there any tem. solution ????
just wanna check that is this app is working or not ..

Comment: can i prevent SQL injection vulnerability using some input type validation ??
m new in php ...

Comment: Check your database user privileges - it's possible to set a user to only be able to perform certain tasks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should escape your strings with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$uMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_mail']);
$uIMEI = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_IMEI']);
$uName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_name']);
$uPass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_pass']);
$tName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_names']);
$tIMEI = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_IMEIs']);
$tDesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_desc']);
mysql_query("UPDATE user_master SET t_names='$tName',t_IMEIs='$tIMEI',t_desc= '$tDesc'      WHERE u_mail = '$uMail' AND u_IMEI = '$uIMEI'");
```

and make sure `$uMail` and `$uIMEI` are set correctly